# select last x lines

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show the last 10 lines of a table ordered by date added ascending.

I know I can `select count(*) as total from tableName` and `$offset = 10 - total` then `select * from tableName order by dateadded asc limit 10 offset $offset`

**NOTE:** I need the results to be displayed in reverse, oldest at the top, newest at the bottom therefore simply ordering by desc does not produce what i need

Can this be done in one query?

Comment: `order by dateadded DESC limit 10`. No offset.

Comment: Why do you need an offset? Does `select * from tableName order by dateadded DESC limit 10` not do what you ask?

Comment: @ypercube Updated question, apologies, didn't explain correctly

Comment: Ok, then you have the asnwer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just order DESC...

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
order by dateadded DESC
Limit 10
```

To swap the order of the results

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM tableName
    order by dateadded DESC
    Limit 10
    ) r
ORDER BY dateadded
```

Comment: Thanks! Swapping the order did it